UART pin acting as power pin
We are interfacing an HM-10 BLE module with an STM32F103 development board. When the UART line is idle and the BLE module doesn't have power,the  BLE powers up, this results in damage to the HM-10 Module some times. Unable to figure out why.

UART pins are high output when it is enabled and nothing is being transmitted.
Generally ICs have protection diodes on input. If you have unpowered IC, it will cause the UART pin current to pass through the protection diode to IC supply pin.
So do not configure the UART pin as output when you have an unpowered chip connected to it.

Generally serial ports are used to connect two different systems together, and it's quite natural for one to be on and the other off.  If you use RS-232 level converters on the inputs and outputs it should handle this for you.

@MarkRansom You don't add two RS-232 level converters between two chips that are 2 inches apart on same PCB. That's a poor and expensive workaround instead of any proper solution, such as the software solution I mentioned, or just a logic buffer that can handle input while unpowered.

If they're on the same PCB, there's no reason for one part to be powered when the other isn't.

@MarkRansom There is. Would you e.g. like that your desktop computer implements a standby mode where some parts on on motherboard is powered and some are not? I have a lot of MCU boards that implement a standby mode where only the MCU is running and it turns on the rest of the chips on when going out of standby. Your phone and laptop also tuns off the display when not needed, instead of sending black screen.

Each IC you are using will come with a datasheet that lists "absolute maximum ratings" and "operating ratings".
It is very common for the absolute maximum rating of a digital input, such as a UART receive line, to be stated as something like "VCC + 0.3V".  That means, if you are not providing voltage on the IC's VCC (sometimes VDD) pin, you must not supply voltage on its input, either.
Your particular module appears to be a bottom-of-the-barrel option with very poor documentation... it doesn't tell you the maximum ratings.  However, that doesn't mean that the restriction doesn't exist.  You just aren't told what the limits are.
If you knew the limits, you could use a series resistance to protect the RX pin.  Since you don't, you really must bring the voltage to zero, either by configuring the STM32 chip as @Justme suggests, or by placing a logic buffer in series that is powered by the same voltage as the BLE module (so it turns off at the same time).  If you use a buffer, of course you should check its maximum ratings and make sure to choose one that tolerates high inputs even when unpowered.

Similar to what Ben says above, a series resistor in the TX line will help prevent back feeding of the module. I used a 10k resistor to prevent back feeding of a FT232 USB chip from an M16 micro and it neatly solved the problem.
It also prevented a high current being drawn from the TX pin on the M16 and also allowed the micro to reliably detect when the USB lead was removed.
